# C# RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardInput how to kill the child process when the parent process exits abnormally

Tags: c#, process.start, processstartinfo

My application launches a console application.  Captures output and sends the console application input.  This all works great.  When I am done with the console application I can exit currentProcess without issue.  My problem occurs when my main application crashes or exits irregularly.  The ConsoleExeFile remains in the task manager and is now using up a full core of CPU usage.  I then have to kill the ConsoleExeFile in task manager.

```
        //  Set the options.
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ConsoleExeFile, "");

        //  Set the options.
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        //  Specify redirection.
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //  Create the process.
        currentProcess = new Process();
        currentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        currentProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        currentProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(currentProcess_Exited);
        currentProcess.OutputDataReceived += currentProcess_OutputDataReceived;

        //  start the process.
        currentProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Your question body doesn't entirely match the title. If I understand correctly, you're asking how to automatically kill the child process when the parent process exits abnormally?

Comment: The title has been modified to more accurately portray my problem.

Comment: Thank you,  I have been searching for this and have not been able to find anything.  I will let you know how it works.

Comment: Excellent!  Works like a charm so far.